# Hiding the formula bar in Excel for a specific file

Tags: excel

I would like to hide the formula bar in a specific Excel file and only in this file. I know we can do it with VBA (Application.DisplayFormulaBar = False) but I am wondering if there is another solution like editing the CustomUI file.

Usually I edit the CustomUI file for hiding ribbon, adding custom tabs, ... It would be nice if we can hide the formula bar in this way.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Short answer is: **No**, you cannot.

Unfortunately, you cannot hide it by editing the CustomUI file. The formula bar has to be hidden using VBA. That being said, you can just run the hide operation on the Workbook_open event.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open() 
    Application.DisplayFormulaBar = False 
End Sub
```

You can turn it on/off depending on the active sheet like so:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)

If Sh.Name = "Sheet1" Then
    Application.DisplayFormulaBar = False
Else
    Application.DisplayFormulaBar = True
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But the disadvantge is that all opened Excel sheet will have the formula bar hidden.... I'm seaching for a solution where only current sheet has formula bar hidden.

Comment: Added example how to achieve what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's a 2011 issue, but the solutions shown above don't seem to be the right ones for the problem in question.

If you modify using vba Aplication.whatelse this change applies to the entire excel app

To fix this instead of turning on/off when you open/close the document uses the sheet's activate/deactivate events

This way when your hidden document is turned on and when you turn off swatches.

This works perfect for me, to hide status bar and formula bar.

I leave you code to see how it works

```
Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    Application.DisplayFormulaBar = False
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.DisplayFormulaBar = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by using the workbook activate en deactivate events. 
Just put `Application.DisplayFormulaBar = False` into the activate event and `Application.DisplayFormulaBar = true` in the deactivate event.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid all opened Excel sheet formula bar hidden you can go for hiding the formula for a particular excel.

```
Sub test()

    Sheet1.Unprotect "test"
    Range("A1").FormulaHidden = True ' range which you want to hide formula.

     'your code here
    Sheet1.Protect "test"

End Sub
```

[image]